# Joining the host of a virtual DC to that virtual DC

Tags: active-directory

I am running an Active Directory instance on a Hyper-V VM.

I am aware that there are issues with time synchronisation on a virtualised DC and this can cause all sorts of issues, etc, however I went with this approach for various non-tech reasons.

However, if my DC is in a VM, can I join the host of the DC (a physical server of course) to the virtualised DC? Is there any issue with this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [VM Host needs to join the domain in Virtual Machine](http://serverfault.com/questions/119066/vm-host-needs-to-join-the-domain-in-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can join the domain with the host server, but it's a really bad idea.

It's definitely a "chicken and egg" problem. As the people in John Gardeniers' link found, in order for the DC to be up, the host has to be up, and in order for the host to be up and function correctly, the DC has to be up.

Someone found an answer in making the server start automatically, but I'd highly recommend against that solution, because there are too many things that can go wrong.

Get another machine to function as the DC, make it independent of this stack of machines, and consider bare metal virtualization if you're looking to run production machines in VMs.